# Convert a unix timestamp to a human readable date in PHP?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have a timestamp value from PHP: `1188604800000`

When I format the time to human readable like this:

```
date("m/d/Y", 1188604800000)
```

It prints:

```
05/21/39635
```

If I put the number into an online Unix Timestamp converter I get:

```
Sat, 01 Sep 2007 00:00:00 GMT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP uses seconds-based timestamps, so divide `1188604800` by `1000` and you are good.

```
php> echo date('Y-m-d', 1188604800000/1000);
2007-09-01
```

Comment: For some strange reason I had to add 86400 to get the right date to show up (it was off by a day). Thanks for the code snippit

Answer (score 6):

I was having trouble with my date being one day off and I had to manually set the default timezone to match my location by using

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Perth"); ?>
```

A list of support timezones can be found here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

(I don't have enough rep to comment so can someone merge that with the actual answer?)